# Unix join command not working for all records in input files

Tags: unix, join

I have 2 input files

**file1:**

```
20191002;XS2031643435;106.802239
20191003;XS2031642890;99.997178
```

**file2:**

```
  ;XS2031643435;210074;CLNPRU200123AUD;AUD_CORP;
  ;XS2031642890;210068;CLNMAS011119SGD;SGD_CORP;
```

Now am trying to join these file contents using below command:

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -t';' -o 1.1,2.5,2.4,1.3 file1 file2
```

Which gives me output:

```
20191002;AUD_CORP;CLNPRU200123AUD;106.802239
```

**Any idea why second line is missing?**

I am expecting it to be like:

```
20191002;AUD_CORP;CLNPRU200123AUD;106.802239
20191003;SGD_CORP;CLNMAS011119SGD;99.997178
```

Actually its part of 2 big input files (~150 records), in which most of the pairs are getting joined as expected except two entries. so i picked those 2 entries and created sample files as above. now first one started coming but still not the second one. any help would be really appreciated.

edits:

```
bash-4.4$ od -b file1
0000000 062 060 061 071 061 060 060 062 073 130 123 062 060 063 061 066
0000020 064 063 064 063 065 073 061 060 066 056 070 060 062 062 063 071
0000040 012 062 060 061 071 061 060 060 063 073 130 123 062 060 063 061
0000060 066 064 062 070 071 060 073 071 071 056 071 071 067 061 067 070
0000100 012
0000101


od -b file2
0000000 073 130 123 062 060 063 061 066 064 063 064 063 065 073 062 061
0000020 060 060 067 064 073 103 114 116 120 122 125 062 060 060 061 062
0000040 063 101 125 104 073 101 125 104 137 103 117 122 120 073 012 073
0000060 130 123 062 060 063 061 066 064 062 070 071 060 073 062 061 060
0000100 060 066 070 073 103 114 116 115 101 123 060 061 061 061 061 071
0000120 123 107 104 073 123 107 104 137 103 117 122 120 073 012
0000136
```

I don't know much about this hexdump, but if it help you..

Comment: On my system I get the expected output of two lines. Please show in your question  hexdumps of the two files.

Comment: thanks bodo, i have added hexdump details in main section. I dont know much about hexdumps, so if you could get something out of it, please let us know..

Comment: The octal dumps are identical to the files (`file1`, `file2`) on my Ubuntu 19.04 system. As I already wrote, with these files the `join...` command prints exactly the expected two lines of output. On which OS does the problem occur? In case your `join` command supports `join --version`, show its output.

Comment: Use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on mouse-selected text to get the proper formatting for code/data/errMsgs. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @Bodo am still not able to get the expected result:

Server : SunOS 5.11 (i86pc)

Comment: @RashidKunimmal Sorry, I don't have a SunOS system to test this. I cannot reproduce your problem on a Linux (Ubuntu 19.04) system. Please confirm in your question that you can really reproduce the problem with the two files shown in the question and not only when these data are embedded in bigger files.

Comment: Hi bodo, thanks i got the expected result.
We have to sort file before using join command, so earlier i sorted file using simple command "sort filename > newfile"

But the file was not sorted according to key value (second column), which caused the issue. Now i am sorting based on join key using command "sort -t";" -k2 filename" So that i am able to sort it based on key field and join condition is working as expected..